# Selenium error when scraping for images: no such element

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I was scraping my website and I need to get images and text within the posts and I encountered this error message I'm not too sure on why its showing this error message as the post has an src element and it has text any information on this will be helpful

```py
    import csv
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    # disable chromedriver log message in cmd
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation", "enable-logging"])
    
    service = Service(executable_path="C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    
    driver.get("https://navalcommand.enjin.com/forum/m/11178354/viewforum/2989688/page/1")
    # get number of pages
    num_pages = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.text.rightmost").text.split(' ')[1]
    
    for page in range(2, int(num_pages)):
        # find all threads on the current page
        threads = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.thread-view.thread-subject")))
        # get links to threads
        thread_links = [x.get_attribute('href') for x in threads]
        # open each link and get all the posts in thread
        for link in thread_links:
            driver.get(link)
            thread_content = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.post-content")
            # get thread id
            thread_id = driver.current_url.split('d/')[1].split('-')[0]
            # save received data in csv
            for post in thread_content:
                post_content = post.text or post.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'img').get_attribute('src')
                with open(file=r'C:\Users\jammi\OneDrive\Desktop\Navcom\aar\ ' f'{thread_id}_naval-command.csv', mode='a',
                          encoding="utf-8") as f:
                    writer = csv.writer(f, lineterminator='\n')
                    writer.writerow([post_content])
        driver.get(f"https://navalcommand.enjin.com/forum/viewforum/2989694/m/11178354/page/{page}")
    
    driver.quit()
```

[image]

Comment: It says there are no `img` tags in the section you were examining.

Comment: what do you see in DevTools in web browser when it shows error? If it uses JavaScript to add element then it may need time for this and you may need to sleep or use [Waits](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/)

Comment: To my understanding its because it can grab jpgs but not pngs I have added waits until everything is loaded then it grabs what it needs and I still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

As @Tim Roberts mentioned, the `img` tag is not present within each post of a thread. I selected the first thread, and ran the following modified code:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

# open each link and get all the posts in thread
for i,link in enumerate(thread_links):
    if i == 1: break
    driver.get(link)
    thread_content = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.post-content")
    # get thread id
    thread_id = driver.current_url.split('d/')[1].split('-')[0]
    # search for img, if present get 'src'
    for post in thread_content:
        try: 
            img = post.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'img')
            post_content = img.get_attribute('src')
        except NoSuchElementException:
            #print("post doesn't have img")
            post_content = post.text
        print(post_content)
```

And for the chosen thread, here is the redacted output:

```
https://cdn.discordapp.com/.../NC_100x100.png
It will be my pleasure ...
As your new General Operations ...
As the Command Sergeant Major ...
as guy the man ...
Just shidded my ...
Smells like ...
```

Comment: Thank you I've modified it to work for what I'm going for and its working as expected